# Fiddler style application in C#

Tags: c#, xml, http, trace

I need to write a fiddler "lite" Windows forms application to perform some HTTP tracing of messages. Specifically I need to show the request/response XMLs to a server as they are occurring, highlighting certain elements etc.

Could anyone point me to a F/OSS application doing something similar as a starter, or perhaps outline the classes I need to use? I am a bit of a newbie with networking classes in C# and appreciate all help.

p.s. I cannot use Fiddler directly for several reasons, so that's not a valid answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [.NET Network Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824.aspx). Then your project would become mostly an exercise in log parsing.

Answer (score 2):

[SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/sharppcap/index.php?title=Main_Page) might be what you want